Excessive use of vias
I am designing a four-layer board, with the layers as follows: Signal - Ground - Power - Signal. The microcontroller I will be using is an ESP32-S3, which I believe delivers an SPI-frequency of 80 MHz. I am integrating three slave devices.
I know it is advised to minimize the amount of vias for specific signals, so my question is: is the amount of vias used as in the attached image problematic for SPI?


At 80MHz? Yes, you will have signal integrity and EMI issues.

What way to route the traces would you recommend?

Why are there vias on FSPI_Q at all, going towards C5?

This is a modified repost of your previously deleted question; note that doing this is against EE.SE rules. If you want to modify your question, there is an edit button at the bottom left of the question.

@TimothyNguyen - Hi, As commented already, doing a "delete & repost" (even if the repost is slightly modified) is breaking the site rules, as it is evading one of the quality control mechanisms. || You received an answer here so you have got away with breaking the rules this time. However please do not "delete & repost" a question again. If (as with your last question) it was "closed" waiting for you to add details, please edit that question to add the details. Ask on our [Meta] if that's unclear or if you want help to understand the site rules. TY

Vias at 80 MHz is ok, but this layout is absolutely not ok. It will lead to disastrous EMI and signal integrity issues.
When you cross from L1 to L4, return current will go from L2 to L3, i.e. you must have a nearby return current via for every signal via. If you insist on the (bad) layer choice of having different power nodes on L2 and L3, then you actually need two return current vias and a local capacitor to connect L2 and L3.
Much simpler is to have both L2 and L3 as the same node (e.g. GND) and use a single return current stitching via between L2 and L3 next to all signal vias.

Rick Hartley discusses this in his presentation How to Achieve Proper Grounding from 1:28:33 to 1:35:38. I've watched this presentation several times, and learn something new from it every time.

@C.Dunn Indeed! For me as an EE autodidact, the presentations of Rick Hartley and Todd Hubing have been what has completely undone the magical knot of EMI understanding
